# How to keep data on each component from an array of the same component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

how do you handle data inside an array of the same component duplicated. I have an array of the same react component generated using the code below:

```
setStatementArray(
    response.data.map((statement, index) => {
      return (
          <Statement 
          key={index}
          currentStep={index + 1}
          statementText={statement.statement} 
          statementId={statement.id} 
        />
      )
    })
  );
```

I tried giving each component it's own state but the states reset when I render components in order. I want to store information for each component inside it. Is that possible?

I render the component like this:

```
<div className="App">
      { 
        statementArray[currentStepIndex]
      }

      <Buttons 
        currentStep={currentStepIndex}
        next={next}  
        back={back}  
      />

</div>
```